# Saving images using Octave but appearing fuzzy upon realoading

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I am enrolled in a Coursera Machine Learning course where I am learning about neural networks. I got some hand-written digits data from this link: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Now I want to convert these data in to `.jpg` format, and I am using this code.

```
function nx=conv(x)
nx=zeros(size(x));
for i=1:size(x,1)
    c=reshape(x(i,:),20,20);
    imwrite(c,'data.jpg','jpg')
    nx(i,:)=(imread('data.jpg'))(:)';
    delete('data.jpg');
end
end
```

Then, I run the above code with:

```
nx=conv(x);
```

`x` is 5000 training examples of handwritten digits. Each training example is a 20 x 20 pixel grayscale image of a digit. Each pixel is represented by a floating point number indicating the grayscale intensity at that location.

The 20 x 20 grid of pixels is "unrolled" into a 400-dimensional vector. Each of these training examples becomes a single row in our data matrix `x`. This gives us a 5000 x 400 matrix `x` where every row is a training example for a handwritten digit image.

After I run this code, I rewrite an image to disk to check:

```
imwrite(nx(1,:),'check.jpg','jpg')
```

However, I find the image is fuzzy. How would I convert these images correctly?

Comment: I would avoid making a function called `conv`, as it would override the `conv` function in the image processing toolbox for convolution.

Comment: @eigenchris - Agreed.  Call it `convert`, or something more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the images using JPEG, which is a **lossy** compression algorithm to save the images.  Lossy compression algorithms guarantee a high compression ratio, but at the expense of slightly degrading your image.  That's probably why you are seeing fuzzy images as it is attributed to compression artifacts.

From the looks of it, you want to save **exactly** what the data should be to file.  As such, use a **lossless** compression algorithm instead, like PNG.  Therefore, change your saving line of code to use PNG:

```
imwrite(c,'data.png','png')
nx(i,:)=(imread('data.png'))(:)';
delete('data.png');
```

Also:

```
imwrite(nx(1,:),'check.png','png')
```

Comment: That doesn't work, however, when I remove this line: 'nx=zeros(size(x));'      It give me correct result. thx ^_^

Comment: yeah, using jepg is OK

Comment: @ZihaoLi - Oh yes.  You are declaring the size of `nx` wrong at the start.  I should have seen that.  Well, it's up to you... I don't even know whether or not you should accept my answer as I didn't really help you lol.  But you said "fuzzy" which is why I suggested what I did in my answer.

Comment: Actually I have already tried use other format, I should write it in my question. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @ZihaoLi - no worries at all.  best of luck.